# Although static gives an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, mvchtmlstring

I'm writing a helper about datetime.

```
public static class DatepickerHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Datepicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value = null, object htmlAttributes = null, EInputAddonPosition? addonPosition = EInputAddonPosition.Right, EInputGroupSize? groupSize = EInputGroupSize.Medium, EDateTimePickerFormat? Format = EDateTimePickerFormat.GunAyYil, bool? showRemoveButton = false, string onChangeFn = "");

    public static MvcHtmlString DatepickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null, EInputAddonPosition? addonPosition = EInputAddonPosition.Right, EInputGroupSize? groupSize = EInputGroupSize.Medium, EDateTimePickerFormat? Format = EDateTimePickerFormat.GunAyYil, bool? showRemoveButton = false, string onChangeFn = "");

    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value);
}
```

all static methods .. looked similar errors but I do not understand

Error:

> DatepickerHelper.DatepickerFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>, object, EInputAddonPosition?, EInputGroupSize?, EDateTimePickerFormat?, bool?, string)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  You've created some methods but they don't have bodies, and because they aren't marked abstract, you're getting an error.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `static` means, are you confusing `abstract` with `static`?

Comment: Is it not enough as "static" markup? . I ask because I do not understand. I ask because I do not understand what I have to do.

"The error message is quite clear." > yes I see, but I do not understand

"The error message is quite clear." > yes I see, but I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods require a method body.

Your current implementation literally does nothing.

This will get you past your current error, but please note the `throw new NotImplementedException();` - you'll need to actually implement the method, and return an appropriate value.

```
public static class DatepickerHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Datepicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value = null, object htmlAttributes = null, EInputAddonPosition? addonPosition = EInputAddonPosition.Right, EInputGroupSize? groupSize = EInputGroupSize.Medium, EDateTimePickerFormat? Format = EDateTimePickerFormat.GunAyYil, bool? showRemoveButton = false, string onChangeFn = "")
    {
        //notice there's a body to this static method now
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public static MvcHtmlString DatepickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null, EInputAddonPosition? addonPosition = EInputAddonPosition.Right, EInputGroupSize? groupSize = EInputGroupSize.Medium, EDateTimePickerFormat? Format = EDateTimePickerFormat.GunAyYil, bool? showRemoveButton = false, string onChangeFn = "")
    {
        //notice there's a body to this static method now
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        //notice there's a body to this static method now
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```